# Jekyll and Redcarpet (plus dependencies)

Tags: ruby, jekyll, redcarpet

Up until a few hours ago, I had my jekyll install working as normal. Having created 26 different posts using my current setup, I'm not expecting something to suddenly not work at all. Ran `jekyll build` to see the results of a new post I created for my blog. I got an error saying it could not find redcarpet; weird since I have never touched my config or anything since I created it. I ran `bundle install` no new gems added. For sanity's sake I ran `bundle show redcarpet`, it could not be found. Okay that's weird. So I run `gem install redcarpet v 3.1.0` which was the version I was using pretty much the entire time. I then run `bundle install` again, checking to see if redcarpet was added...and nope.

I decided to go into my config and switch markdown parser and add kramdown, then run jekyll serve...and now I get that I'm missing kramdown and like redcarpet even if I install via gem install jekyll refuses to acknowledge it's existence.

I tried deleting my gemfile and rebuilding it unfortunately that does nothing. If I run `bundle exec jekyll serve` it works however redcarpet isn't activated and thus the markdown isn't parsed correctly (And new entries aren't added to the index page).

I'm probably missing something obvious, any direction or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: Jekyll version + a repository and I'll try to reproduce.

Comment: From jekyll Gemfile : `gem 'redcarpet', '~> 3.2.3'`

Comment: where is jekyll Gemfile located?